# How to align a camera to another camera view?

Tags: camera

I have an animated camera A with tracking modifiers to track an object.

I would like to generate an static camera at frame 200 from the exact look of camera A.
How do I do this? This seems tricky but should not be?

thanks :-)

Comment: Go to frame where your camera A looks where you want static camera to look to. Duplicate camera A. Remove modifiers. Done.

Comment: I tried that, Removing the modifiers (tracking) actually changes slightly the view again, dont know why?

Comment: Generally this is the right answer! But If it's not working, maybe just manually copying the contents of the Transform tab of the camera object into the duplicate will work for you?